# Coffeescript, nodeunit and global variables

Tags: node.js, coffeescript, nodeunit

I have a web app written in Coffeescript that I'm testing with nodeunit, and I can't seem to get access to global variables ("session" vars in the app) set in the test:

src/test.coffee

```
root = exports ? this

this.test_exports = ->
    console.log root.export
    root.export
```

test/test.coffee

```
exports["test"] = (test) ->
    exports.export = "test"
    test.equal test_file.test_exports(), "test"
    test.done()
```

Results in output:

```
test.coffee
undefined
✖ test

AssertionError: undefined == 'test'
```

How do I access globals across tests?

Comment: Try to compile it with the `b`-Flag. This prevents the security closure from being added.

Comment: My source is compiled with the flag:  `nice -n 19 coffee -o web/ -b -c -w src/`, I added the -b to Trevor Burnham's continuous Cakefile build = (watch, callback) ->
 if typeof watch is 'function'
  callback = watch
  watch = false
 options = ['-b', '-c', '-o', 'lib', 'src']
 options.unshift '-w' if watch
but no dice.

Comment: Try not using global variables?

Comment: Valid, but I'm porting my application to coffeescript and refactoring for unit tests on node, and I'd rather leave the de-globalizing of the  session data as a last step. In addition, it may not be worth the marginal increase in complexity to ditch the globals.

Answer (score 1):

Create fake `window` exported global for node:

src/window.coffee

```
exports["window"] = {}
```

src/test.coffee

```
if typeof(exports) == "object"
    window = require('../web/window')

this.test_exports = ->
    console.log window.export
    window.export
```

test/test.coffee

```
test_file = require "../web/test"
window = require "../web/window'"

exports["test"] = (test) ->
    window.export = "test"
    test.equal test_file.test_exports(), "test"
    test.done()
```

Not very elegant, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can share global state using the "global" object.

one.coffee:

```
console.log "At the top of one.coffee, global.one is", global.one
global.one = "set by one.coffee"
```

two.coffee:

```
console.log "At the top of two.coffee, global.one is", global.one
global.two = "set by two.coffee"
```

Load each one from a third module (an interactive session in this example)

```
$ coffee
coffee> require "./one"; require "./two"
At the top of one.coffee, global.one is undefined
At the top of two.coffee, global.one is set by one.coffee
{}
```

Comment: I fixed the example code to use "root" instead of "this" (if that was the particular you're referring to).  Still no love.  Basically, I'm assuming if I attach a var to `exports` in my test, I should be able to access it from `exports` in any file in the same node vm.

Comment: Yeah but there's no magic "export" variable.  That is undefined since you haven't defined it. root vs this doesn't matter.

Comment: You're correct that "export" has no magic, but neither does "foo", "bar", "monkey", or "cheetah". To put it simply: How does one share data across files in node?

Comment: "exports" with an s.  It's already working or else your test wouldn't even run.  Just do "exports.foo = 42" in mod1.coffee and "mod1 = require 'mod1';console.log mod1.foo" in test.coffee.

Comment: I get that the global object in node is `exports` with an s.  The code above is using it both to the publish the test and, theoretically, publish the variable (unfortunately named) `export`.  I can't have `src/test.coffee` import `test/test.coffee`--it can't know about the test, obviously. In short, the answer is, you can't access globals in node without explicitly `require`-ing them.

Comment: If you want to make sure your test framework doesn't hard code your specific tests, you can locate tests on the filesystem and then require them by path without hard coding their name.  Have you considered reading the source of one or more of the test frameworks out there?  Check out mocha or jasmine-node, for example.

Comment: I'm using a test framework, nodeunit, the tests get executed fine, continuously, in fact as changes are made to the test files.  The problem is simply that I wanted a transparent means to simulate the global namespace of the browser in the node environment without a `require`.  It can't be done.